# Deploying parse Server example to Digital Ocean

Tags: parse-platform, digital-ocean

I successfully deployed  [parse server example](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example) to heroku and access it with parse dashboard.

Now I want to deploy it to Digital Ocean but I 'm not getting any clue that how to achieve this. I already spent hours on this but didn't find anything enough clear to follow.

Advise to towards right direction

(I know this doesn't meet the requirements of stack overflow's question criteria, but what to do when you don't 've anything to start. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digital Ocean has a pretty straight tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-parse-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)
I have followed it and can certified it does work.

Comment: I have seen it
but couldn't follow (due first interaction with digital ocean
How ever thanks

Comment: I recommend you do this tutorial first to configure your server: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-14-04